# Is it possible to edit a layer from Esri Personal Geodatabase in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, ms-access

After a lot of research and effort I have successfully made a connection to my Esri Personal Geodatabase (.mdb file).

Now I want to edit some attribute data in the attribute table of a layer... BUT I can't because the toggle edit and the editing toolbar is greyed out.

So how do I edit a layer inside (.mdb) file that I have loaded into QGIS?!

I am using QGIS 3.

Don't ask me why I want to do it this way. (But If you wan to know why, it's because I want to edit the (.mdb)file in QGIS and then send it to someone who is using ArcMap who should be able to read/write to the file too. The other person has ArcMap and I have QGIS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom line here is you can't. Here's a list of [files you can edit within QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/278480/118015). As you can see, .mdb files are not in there, because OGR/GDAL don't handle writing .mdb files (they only support reading).

If you're working with someone using Esri software, you could ask them to convert the files to a format you can both work with. Or you could save the .mdb layer as a format that you can edit, like shp.

Either way, you unfortunately have to change the format.