# Points to shapefile, with curved lines given center and radius (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon

I'm a newbie in GIS and for a project I need to create a shapefile given some points in lat/lon. I have been following this tutorial: https://community.pyramidanalytics.com/t/q5tk8w/creating-a-shapefile-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates and it's OK for polygons but I need some lines to be curved.

My data is described given vertices and circles, like this: *3400N 02500W; 3000N 02000W; 3139N 01725W from this point following an arc of a circle 100 NM centred on 3304N 01621W up to 3130N 01545W...* and then it continue giving the points of the vertices of the polygon.

(There are other curved parts as well, described like the above part, but I think with one example I'd be able to do the others).

How can I solve this?

Comment: shape file specification does not support /allow curved line. shapefiles of type line are always connected by straight lines

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like parcel or cadastral data. Try one of these plugins (descriptions copied directly from plugin directory):

> **CoGo Plugin**
>
> A plugin to capture coordinates, bearings and distances and to use
>   these to construct and manage land parcels.

-

> **BoundaryDelineation** (This plugin is experimental)
>
> Supports interactive delineation of visible (cadastral) boundaries in
>   orthoimages
>
> The plugin is designed to support the interactive delineation of
>   visible (cadastral) boundaries in orthoimages. This work is supported
>   by its4land, which is part of the Horizon 2020 program of the European
>   Union (project number 687828).
>
> Video Tutorial:  https://youtu.be/f6an86_-OaY

There are also plugins available for cadastre data for specific regions/languages, including France, Germany, Spain, Slovak and Columbia. Find them by searching for "cadast" in the plugin manager.

As Erik and Kurt pointed out, the shapefile format cannot store a curve. These plugins will help you enter the data, which will be converted to vertices connected by straight lines. If you need it to be *stored* as curves, look into some of the many other [data formats supported by QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/142790/81764); there's probably some that can store curves.

These Wikipedia pages may also be interesting:

- [Metes and Bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metes_and_bounds)
- [Cadastre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadastre)
- [Plat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plat)
- [Lot and Block Survey System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lot_and_block_survey_system)

Answer (score 1):

Put all points into a shapefile, either by manually entering them in QGIS, or by putting them into a csv and loading it into QGIS.

`Buffer` the points which are the center of any arc by the given distance (yes, you'll have to convert to km first), then manually draw the polygons using `snapping` by connecting the points and arcs in the correct order.

Also, note on the side: The common combination of QGIS and shapefile can't do curves. Anything which poses as a curve or circle is just enough points connected by short, straight lines so they seem to form a curve. As @ndawson pointed out, there are some file types which are able to store true curves, and you also are able to manually add curves via the `shape digitzing` toolbar (https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#add-circular-string).

Comment: Fyi : qgis does have full support for true curved geometries, I've removed your note from the end of the answer.

Comment: Don't hurl fragments of information at us, please expand @ndawson. I haven't heard of it.

Comment: It's been supported since qgis 2.10 - check the changelog

Comment: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog210/index.html#feature-new-geometry-engine

Comment: Supported when using PostGIS - that's something different than using plain QGis.

Comment: Well, in 2.10 it was only PostGIS. Now it's oracle, geopackage, shapefiles, ...

Comment: And again you're hurling fragments. I haven't seen any option to create a curve using shapefiles so far.

Comment: Fine. Have some more "fragments". https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/fd0fba70/src/core/providers/memory/qgsmemoryprovider.cpp#L615  https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/ffded6f1/src/core/qgsvectordataprovider.cpp#L301 https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/51f6fb06/src/providers/delimitedtext/qgsdelimitedtextprovider.cpp#L1118 https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/eb08839/src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp#L1268 https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/109fcc0a/src/providers/ogr/qgsogrprovider.cpp#L2608 https://www.gdal.org/classOGRLayer.html#aeedbda1a62f9b89b8e5f24332cf22286 . Happy now?

Comment: Nope. If you know how to do it, why don't you simply add a simple description of how to do so in the first place.

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#add-circular-string